Prove that $\frac{I\cap J}{IJ}\cong\frac{k[x,y]}{\langle xy\rangle}$ for $I=\langle x^2y \rangle$ and $J=\langle xy^2\rangle$
$R=k[x,y]$ is a $R$ module,where $k$ is a field. $I=\left<x^2y\right>$ and $J=\langle xy^2\rangle$. Prove that
$$\frac{I\cap J}{IJ}\cong\frac{k[x,y]}{\left<xy\right>}$$ as $R$ modules.
This is how far I have reached.
$IJ=\left<x^3y^3\right>$, $I\cap J=\left<x^2y^2\right>$
So the question translates to proving
$$\frac{\left<x^2y^2\right>}{\left<x^3y^3\right>}\cong\frac{k[x,y]}{\left<xy\right>}$$
I tried to show the isomorphism by quotienting the injectve function from $\left<x^2y^2\right>$ to $k[x,y]$ and showing that the kernal of the resulting map is $\left<x^3y^3\right>$. But it didn't work since the kernal tuned out to be $\left<x^2y^2\right>$.
I also think $I+J=\left<xy\right>$. Can someone tell me where I am making mistake

Try coming up with a different map $\langle x^2y^2\rangle\to k[x,y]$, one that's not $0$ after taking the quotient. Or/and a map in the different direction.

If you want a ring isomorphism, then there is no such isomorphism. What kind of isomorphism are you requering?

@BrancoFloresRocha I am looking for an R-module isomorphism. I will add that to the question

Did you try to use the universal property of quotient?
